# Puppeteer footer only display on last page

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have got a problem with the footerTemplate parameter of Puppeteer : the footer is only shown in the last page of the document. I want it to be displayed on every page of the document (well... a footer).

Maybe am I not using the parameters correctly ?

Here is my Puppeteer pdf generation :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://localhost:8000/?' + parameters);
await page.pdf({
    path: path,
    format: 'A4',
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: '<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>'
});
await browser.close();
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on my experience with the lib, header / footer are goes behind the content of the page.
Try setting some margins to make them visible:

```
await page.pdf({
    path: path,
    format: 'A4',
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: '<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>',
    margin : {
            top: '20px',
            right: '20px',
            bottom: '20px',
            left: '20px'
        };
});
```

Comment: That's it ! Adding a bottom margin fixed the footer not displaying. I also added a local style based on Bernhard link to issue. Thank you !

Comment: Seems to depend on the HTML layout... It only worked on a single page for me, but for multi-page I had to use the `@media print ; @print` as suggested below.

Answer (score 5):

I came up to this problem as well, and margin settings for puppeteer did not work for me, as my whole webpage was a table. So even though I set bottom margin in puppeteer, the footer was still under the content. I fixed it with the following CSS:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue but was able to reproduce it.

When searching for text "THIS IS A TEST" it's found as often as the amount of pages in the PDF... But only on the last page the text "THIS IS A TEST" has a color.

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for "THIS IS A TEST".

**Look on a page within the document it's there but not shown (marked due to search):**

[image]

**But on the last page it's visible:**

[image]

There's an open issue on gitHub related to yours [puppeteer/issues/1853](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1853)

Comment: Yes you are right, "THIS IS A TEST" is really on every pages ! The problem seems to be a margin problem combined with the style problem you linked to. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I needed to change my margins from

```
marginTop: 100,
marginBottom: 70
```

to

```
margin: {
        top: '100px',
        bottom: '70px',
    }
```