# Puppeteer PDF Header Not Showing On Every Page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf-generation, puppeteer

So I am currently just trying to put a simple header on top of all my PDF pages however the header shows fine on only the first page. The rest of the pages do not seem to render the header. I had no problems like this with getting my footer to work.

I am getting my margins in the pdf generation like so:

```js
   const pdf = await page.pdf({
            format: "A4",
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {top: "2cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "100px", left: "1cm" },
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            headerTemplate: headerHtml,
            footerTemplate: footerHtml
        });
```

The `headerHtml` variable is linked to this HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #header,
        #footer {
            padding: 0cm 1cm 0 1cm !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style='height: 100%; width: 100%;'>
        <div style="height: 100%; width:100%;">

        </div>
        <hr style='height:0.5px;border:none;color:#CCCCCC;background-color:#CCCCCC;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; margin-top:auto;' />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So on the top of the first page I see this as expected:
[image: First Page]

Then on the second page and every page after that it disappears?

[image: Second Page]

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Puppeteer footer only display on last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985955/puppeteer-footer-only-display-on-last-page) you should try to keep increasing your margin until you see it.

Also don't forget to apply a font-size like 12px to your footer/header content to be sure to see it. Without it my footer were barely visible on my page.